# How to replace a list comprehension with a numpy command?

Tags: python, list, numpy

Is there a way to replace the following python list comprehension with a numpy function that doesn't work with loops?

```py
a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3])

bins = np.bincount(a)
>>> bins: [2 3 0 1]


a_counts = [bins[val] for val in y_true]
>>> a_counts: [2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

So the basic idea is to generate an array where the actual values are replaced by the number of occurrences of that specific value in the array.

I want to do this calculation in a custom keras loss function which, to my knowledge, doesn't work with loops or list comprehensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to index the result from [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) with `a`:

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3])
bins = np.bincount(a)
a_counts = bins[a]
```

---

```
print(a_counts)
# array([2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Little follow up question:
I tried doing the same thing in keras using tf backend with the same arrays:

```python    
bins = k.tf.bincount(y_true)
    y_true_counts = bins[y_true]
```

Unfortunately I get the following error: 
Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice_10' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [?], [1,6], [1,6], [1].

Answer (score 0):

Or use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
l = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3]
print(Counter(l))
```

Which Outputs:

```
Counter({1: 3, 0: 2, 3: 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid loops, you may use `pandas` library:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3])
a_counts = pd.value_counts(a)[a].values
>>> a_counts: array([2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1], dtype=int64)
```